# jQuery toggle with active class

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a menu with "yes / no" options just like this.

[image]

The red color box containing word "yes" is my active button. I just want to show another options when users click **yes**. So I used jQuery toggle function.

When page load, it showing menu with options just like this.

[image]

But **I don't want to show it until users click yes.** I figured out the problem. It happened because **yes** button has an active class activated. That's why it showing its options. And also I need to hide that toggle menu options when click **no**.

I tried with jquery hide functions adding another class to **no**. It seems ok but expert advice needed.

```
$(".remove-toggle").click(function(){
 $(".wrap").hide();
});
```

Working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jayD2/jkLank8b/10/) here.

Comment: add all relevant code to OP not in a link. Link rots making the OP useless for future readers

Comment: I got you. Will update asap.

Comment: If it works, why would you need help then?

Comment: Well, if you want the user to click yes, just show the `No` option as the higlighted one and make sure to start with the `.wrap` hidden.

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: Please read all question first.

Comment: Optional menu is showing on page load. " I don't want to show it until users click yes."

Comment: @Cristy: My client needs "yes" option highlighted always.

Comment: @CssSY That makes no sense. Why would `Yes` be highlighted when `No` is the currently selected option?

Comment: @Cristy Good point. If yes is selected already, the user will never clicks that yes button again. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, what you have looks fine, except that clicking 'yes' twice will hide and show, and you don't want that. To solve that, use `fadeIn` instead of `fadeToggle` for the `.click()` JQuery function.

To solve the other problem, use this CSS:

```
.wrap {
  display: none;
}
```

And remove the `active` class from the 'yes' button.
See this:

```js
$('.btn-switch').click(function() {
    var $group = $(this).closest('.form-group');
    $('.btn-switch', $group).removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
  });
  $(".activate-toggle").click(function() {
    $(".wrap").fadeIn();
  });
  $(".remove-toggle").click(function() {
    $(".wrap").fadeOut();
  });
```

```css
.btn-switch.active {
  background: #e46a5d!important;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-shadow: none;
}
.wrap {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="member" class="col-md-5 col-sm-12 control-label">
    Do you have the car right now?
  </label>
  <div class="col-lg-10">
    <div class="btn-group">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-switch activate-toggle"> <span class="goods">Yes</span>
      </button>
      <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-switch remove-toggle"><span class="services">No</span>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="wrap">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="lastname" class="col-md-5 col-sm-12 control-label">Qualification type</label>
    <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-7 col-sm-12 form-input">
      <input type="text" class="form-control input-std" id="qualification-type">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @CssSY Toggle means that if it's selected, unselect it. If it's unselected, then it will select it. If you use toggle, there is no need for a 'No' button

Comment: Ah I see. Do you know any transitions other that jquery fadeIn?

Comment: Thank you very much. What if I need to use multiple questions? Am I need to repeat code or any best practice?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146042/discussion-between-james-douglas-and-csssy).

Comment: Send you replies but no response from your side.

Comment: @CssSY Sorry, this is a different chat room.

Answer (score 2):

Just add this css.

```
.wrap {
   display: none;
 }
```

Then, the .wrap class will not be visible at the beginning itself.

Here is the fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/jkLank8b/12/

Comment: Works great as my requirement. Thanks!

Comment: Is that ok to use $(".wrap").hide(); when user clicks "no"?

Comment: Sure. What if I need to use multiple questions? Am I need to repeat code or any best practice?

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you need?
- the active class was removed from the HTML element. So white will be the starting background color for both buttons.
- the element with the .wrap class is hidden by default.
- Instead of making .wrap visible via jQuery, I defined a class with animation and use jQuery to add and remove the class when necessary.

```js
  $('.btn-switch').click(function() {
    var $group = $(this).closest('.form-group');
    $('.btn-switch', $group).removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
  });

  $(".activate-toggle").click(function() {
    $(".wrap").addClass('animate-wrap-show');
  });

  $(".remove-toggle").click(function() {
    $(".wrap").removeClass('animate-wrap-show');
  });
```

```css
.wrap {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}
.btn-switch.active {
  background: #e46a5d!important;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-shadow: none;
}
.animate-wrap-show {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="member" class="col-md-5 col-sm-12 control-label">
    Do you have the car right now?
  </label>
  <div class="col-lg-10">
    <div class="btn-group">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-switch activate-toggle"> <span class="goods">Yes</span>
      </button>
      <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-switch remove-toggle"><span class="services">No</span>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="wrap">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="lastname" class="col-md-5 col-sm-12 control-label">Qualification type</label>
    <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-7 col-sm-12 form-input">
      <input type="text" class="form-control input-std" id="qualification-type">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```